# What are specific considerations when reviewing posts on Academia.SE?

Tags: discussion, support, editing

As the users gain higher reputations, they have access to some moderation tools which allows them to review the posts of the website. When reviewing some posts from on Academia.SE;

- Basically, what odd things should a reviewer look for and edit or even rise a flag upon?
- Is s/he required to leave a comment when reviewing posts? If so, please give some template comments (for probable cases).

We have a question on the [main site's meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing) as stated in the [comments](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/what-are-considerations-when-reviewing-first-posts-and-late-answers#comment4527_1288), so please direct yours answer to your specific considerations about reviewing posts on Academia.SE.

Comment: This is covered in some detail at the [main site meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing).